# UI update and delegate in another class doesnt work in separate thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, user-interface, scope

In order to keep responsiveness in the UI, I use a separate thread to execute various process, for example some FTP download.

```
Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
    Dim ThreadResync As System.Threading.Thread
    ThreadResync = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Bodacc_ResyncFTP)
    ThreadResync.Start()
End Sub

Sub Bodacc_ResyncFTP()
    Dim MyBodacc As bodacc_data = New bodacc_data
    MyBodacc.Label_Status = Form1.Label1
    MyBodacc.ResyncFTP()
End Sub
```

A way to update the UI with threading is the `Delegate` thingy, so in the `bodacc_data` I had to

```
Public Class bodacc_data
    ......
    Delegate Sub UpdateLabelDelg(text As String, ThisLabel As Label)
    Public Delegate_label As UpdateLabelDelg = New UpdateLabelDelg(AddressOf set_label)
    Public Label_Status = Label
    ......
    Sub set_label(stext As String, ThisLabel As Label)
        ThisLabel.Text = stext
    End Sub
    .....

    Sub ResyncFTP()
        //says hello
        If Label_Status.InvokeRequired = True Then
            Label_Status.Invoke(Delegate_label, New Object() {"Working...", Label_Status})
        Else
            Label_Status.Text = "Working..."
        End If

        //do stuff
    End Sub
End Class
```

It works like a charm. But I have many class doing more or less the same (disk update, database update, FTP update) and having to copy/past all the delegate / external label declaration / mini sub / invoke sound silly.

So I created a class to handle those UI update / delegate in order to have a quick access

```
Public Class Form_UI

    Delegate Sub UpdateLabelDelg(text As String, ThisLabel As Label)
    Public Delegate_label As UpdateLabelDelg = New UpdateLabelDelg(AddressOf set_label)

    Private Labels(2) As Label

    Sub New()

        Labels(0) = Form1.Label1
        Labels(1) = Form1.Label2
        Labels(2) = Form1.Label3

    End Sub

    Sub set_label(stext As String, ThisLabel As Label)
        ThisLabel.Text = stext
    End Sub


    Public Sub ChangeLabel(ByVal LabelNum As Integer, nText As String)
        LabelNum = LabelNum - 1

        If Labels(LabelNum).InvokeRequired Then
            Labels(LabelNum).Invoke(Delegate_label, New Object() {nText, Labels(LabelNum)})
        Else
            Labels(LabelNum).Text = nText
            Labels(LabelNum).Update()
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

So, now in the revamped `bodacc_data` and all others processing class I have only :

```
Public Class bodacc_data
    ......
    Private MyUI as Form_UI
    .....
    Sub New()
        MyUI = New Form_UI()
    End Sub

    Sub ResyncFTP()
        //says hello
        MyUI.ChangeLabel(1, "Working...")

        //do stuff
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Question** Why is `MyUI.ChangeLabel` not updating when the `ResyncFTP` is called in a thread, but works if called in the main thread (As in the code sample below)

```
Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
    Dim MyBodacc As bodacc_data = New bodacc_data 
    MyBodacc.ResyncFTP()
End Sub
```

Note that there is no error thrown. The notable weirdness is that `<Form_UI>.ChangeLabel()` never goes the `.Invoke` route but the normal update route. I strongly suspect a scope issue or insight issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a windows forms app you set up a UI thread that is meant to be the owner of all the UI. The UI thread contains the message pump that is used to update all of the UI.

But what you're doing in `Button11_Click` is creating a new thread that goes and calls `Dim MyBodacc As bodacc_data = New bodacc_data` which, in turn, calls `MyUI = New Form_UI()`.

You are creating a form on a non-UI thread. There is no message pump and therefore the UI doesn't update.

Comment: I see, Following your explanation, I changed to have the `New bodacc_data` and `Form_UI` in form_load, so they are created in the UI thread. The separate thread calls now in the already-existing `MyBodacc.ResyncFTP()` and it works . Thanks for the insight !